# How to read higher definition instagram avatar image?

Tags: instagram-api

I am currently able to use the instagram API to read the basic user profile. I am able to get the profile_picture from the returned result via the API call below.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

However, I notice that the avatar image is extremely small - it is 150x150. And extremely pixelated if enlarged on a mobile device.

Is it possible for me to get the avatar image that is higher definition?

If so, what is the API that i need to use?